# Scanning values into a matrix without using [ ] C language

Tags: c, matrix, transpose

I have a problem. I was asked to write a program that transposes a matrix, without using []...for example, i know that if it was a one dimensional array, i could say that array[3] is the same as *(array+3)...but how do i do that with a matrix?

here's my code for scanning:

```
void scan_matrix(matrix mat1,int number_of_rows, int number_of_columns)
{
    int row_index,column_index;
    for(row_index=0;row_index<number_of_rows;row_index++)
    {
        printf("Enter the values of row %d\n",row_index);
        for(column_index=0;column_index<number_of_columns;column_index++)
            scanf("%d",WHAT GOES HERE?????);
    }
}
```

Comment: It depends on what a `matrix` is...

Comment: a two dimensional array. with rows and columns. I'm new at this, sorry if question was unclear.

Comment: @OriaGruber if you are not willing to use [] , then you must use * arithmetic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `mat1` is a simple pointer, then this should do the job for you :

```
for(row_index=0;row_index<number_of_rows;row_index++)
    {
        printf("Enter the values of row %d\n",row_index);
        for(column_index=0;column_index<number_of_columns;column_index++)
            scanf("%d", (mat1 + row_index*number_of_columns + column_index));
    }
```

The program uses the fact that matrices (2-d arrays) are in fact stored as 1-dimensional  arrays in memory.

Lets take a 2d matrix :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

This is stored in memory as :

```
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

So, the correct variable is accessed by using a way to map the logical positions of array elements with the actual positions. All we need is to find out the relation which turns out to be :

```
Pos = Row*Num_Of_Col + Col
```

Answer (score 1):

if mat is two dimensional int array like :  mat[3][3]

then scanf code would be : `scanf("%d",(*(mat+row_index)+column_index));`

```
a[3] : *(a+3)
a[3][3] : (*(a+3)+3)
```